# How open the JSP page of a struts2 action in a popup window

Tags: jsp, struts2

I need to open the JSP called validar.jsp page in a popup window.

The struts.xml code is:

```
<action name="validar" class="validar.action.Validar" method="execute">
  <result name="success">/estructura/validar.jsp</result>
  <result name="input">/estructura/contacto.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

I need to open the validar.jsp page in a popup

The form is:

```
<s:form action="validar">
  <s:textfield ></s:textfield>
  <s:submit valign="middle"></s:submit>
  <s:reset valign="middle"></s:reset>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Popup window, or on-screen dialog box? A *window* is a matter of using the link's `target` attribute. An in-window dialog box is JavaScript.

Comment: Hello,   I know do this, but I don't know how call the JavaScript function that do it rom the strus.xml file.

Comment: You must return a page that will, as soon as it's loaded, invoke some JavaScript that will open a popup window.

Answer (score 1):

Create a modal window on same jsp and add your validator.jsp code in it and put its property hidden initially through css, when you reach this page again, make its property visible.

Hope this will help.